# How to use android libraries in our project

Tags: android, android-library

I have just been introduced to android libraries and have checked out a lot of them. But I have no idea how to use them in my android app.

So can someone post a guide on how to Search, Download, and integrate them in our android project. As I have searched on internet and got to know that we have to put the jar in lib folder, and use the particular classes, but can someone guide how to do the same and how to use them in out layout to give cool effects to our app.

I searched on Stackoverflow but didnt get a satisfactory answer so thats why Im posting it here..

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too broad.  Stack overflow is only for questions which can have specific answers.

Comment: jar is different from library project. jar contains pure .java files. Library project can have resource files as well. so what do you want? This is assuming you have already download .jar or library project

Comment: @ChrisStratton - If answer is not expected then atleast someone can provide some guide from where I can read, understand and implement.

Comment: @Raghunandan - nopes But I think their repos are uploaded on github, I can download them and yeah there is diff between lib projects and jar files, but I dont know what to use and how to use...its seems like I am new to programming, but I am not and will understand pretty quickly but the problem is libraries are new to me and even no tutorial is available anywhere...

Comment: @Shivam http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for the link...will try to read it and understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how many prior knowledge you have but I hope I can help you a bit :)

**Search**

Try to google a library for your special needs. Most of the good libraries can be found on github. There you can see how many people favor the library and how frequently and regularly the library was updated in the past. Try to find useful pages like [www.androidviews.net](http://www.androidviews.net) where nice libraries are collected.

---

**Download**

Usually you can download Libraries as a .jar, as a .zip oder via git.

When you want to use a .jar, you simply have to download it.

When you have a library in the .zip file, you can store it anywhere in your filesystem. The advantage over a .jar is that you can access the code of the library directly.

When you use git, you simply can clone the repository directly from github. Using git is the most elegant way because you can update the library with only one command in the terminal. When you have downloaded a zip and the library has updates, you have to download the library again and replace it. When you want to use git you can find a simple beginner's guide [here](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.html).

---

**Integrate**

When you have a .jar, you have to put it in the *libs* folder at the root of your project where you want to use the library.

When you have a .zip file, run Eclipse, go to *File -> New -> Other...* and choose "Android from existing code". In the next step, choose the unzipped library folder. Sometimes you can choose more than one project because many libraries contain samples, usually you have to choose only one of the projects and not all the samples if you don't need them. Then right click on the imported project and choose *Properties*. In the Android tab, make sure that *Is Library* is checked. Then make another right click to your own project and go also to the Android tab. In the library section, press *Add...* and choose the library.

When you got the library via git follow the same steps after downloading a .zip file.

---

**Usage**

After you followed these steps, the usage of libraries is completely different. Most of the frequently used libraries have a *README.md* file where you can find a tutorial how to use it. [Here](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) you can find a good example for a library which is easy to use. It loads images from the web to an ImageView.

Comment: Hey thanks you cleared almost 95% of my doubts.

I have 2 questions only.

What I have to do after following the above method? I mean do I have to make changes in my layout or what? 

Also can I have different libraries for different layouts? like for my main layout I want to have tabbed view using tabbed view lib. and for Second layout I want to have slide to refresh lib..

Also what impact libs have on the size of the project?

Thanks

Comment: Read few of the Readme.md of few libs and understanding things now...Thanks a lot for your worthy answer...